# How to write PHP variable as HTML attribute value?

Tags: php, html

I am confused about how PHP variable should be written inside an HTML attribute.
In case of HTML form, we write it as

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

Here we echo the PHP variable $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] inside action attribute.

But in my case when I try to get the server name inside img element src attribute then I get the following error

```
<img src="<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ?>/test/image/1.jpg">
```

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

I get this error only when I echo the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. When I remove echo and write it as

```
<img src="<?php $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ?>/test/image/1.jpg">
```

then server finds the image.

So my question is why echo is fine in first case but not in late case?

Comment: In your second case `<?php $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ?>` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Look into the generated HTML - is the URL a valid one? No? Check $_SERVER array for better alternatives...

Answer (score 2):

If you put the server name in the URL, you need to prefix it with `//`. Otherwise, the server name is treated as a directory, not a hostname.

```
<img src="//<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ?>/test/image/1.jpg">
```

But there shouldn't be any need to put the server name there in the first place. By default a URL is looked up on the same server as the page it's contained in. So you can just write:

```
<img src="/test/image/1.jpg">
```

Comment: If your are starting your path in the URL with a `/`, the browser is looking in the absolute path, without a `/` at the beginning the path is treated as relative to your current page. If you have, for example, a URL called `http://example.com/test`, `/image/1.jpg` would be interpreted as `http://example.com/image/1.jpg`. In contrast, `image/1.jpg` would be `http://example.com/test/image/1.jpg`.

Comment: @Johannes — Nobody suggested using a path without a `/` at the front.

Comment: It was just an additional explanation to not run into any errors when trying this. I always try to give some more background information in my comments and answers here because when other people had done it that had saved a lot of debugging hours for me in the past. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

```
<img src="<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/test/image/1.jpg">
```

Probably missed ->  ;

Comment: It is optional at the end of a PHP block.